# How to track the eigenvalue and eigenvector of a matrix depending on its construction

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Let us say I have a block matrix that is `28 x 28` in dimensionality. Like so:

```
B = np.zeros((14,14))
C = np.zeros((14,14))
D = np.zeros((14,14))
Ct = C.T

A = np.block([[B,C], [Ct, D]])
```

I proceed to fill up this matrix, which is irrelevant to the question I am asking so just imagine that we have random values inside of the matrix instead. I want to obtain the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of `A` so I use numpy.linalg for that

```
vals, vecs = np.linalg.eig(A)
```

The documentation of `np.linalg.eig` says that the eigenvalues are "not necessarily ordered" which  I find really ambiguous.

If I use numpy's np.linalg.eig to diagonalize the matrix, I get back the respective eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but "not necessarily ordered".

I don't know what order `np.linalg.eig` chooses to store the vectors and values but if I want the resulting eigenvalues to be sorted in terms of "where" they come from within the block matrix, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but won't the eigenvalues/vectors of A be independent of the eigenvalues/vectors of B, C, and D? Or, if you have a special case (e.g., the determinant of C is zero), why not just calculate the eigenvalues/vectors of B and D independently?

Comment: @AJBiffl yes they will be independent but I don't think that helps me here (please let me know if I am wrong). My question is how can I essentially create a map between the eigenvector and its positioning with respect to matrix A.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "positioning." The only time eigenvalues of a matrix correspond to the elements of the matrix is when the matrix is triangular, and then you can just read the eigenvalues off of the main diagonal. Otherwise, the eigenvalues don't correspond really at all to any "parts" of the matrix - at most you could look at the eigen*vectors* to see if any have zeros in them, but again I'm not sure I'm understanding what you want. Maybe it would be helpful if you could edit your question with an example drawing out what exactly you want to happen?